# del C[0] until the len(C) == 1 with a while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Basically, I want to delete each element to the left of the list until there is one element left. And then break. I am also looping through each index of c as it is a list of sub-lists. I am deleting the first element in an inner list. (eg. list == 1234.... 1234, 234, 34, and finally 4)

Edit: My computer has been very strange lately. If the while loop is not infinite on your computer. Please consider any mistakes I may or could contribute to an infinite loop. I don't know what's going on.

```
r=[];
c = [[1,2],[3,2],[3],[1]]
for j in range(1, len(c)):
    if str(any(elem in c[0] for elem in c[j])) == 'False':
        r.append(c[j])
if j == len(c) - 1:
    del c[0]
    r[:] = []
    print(r, c)
```

Output

```
[] [[3, 2], [3], [1]]
```

**Detailing results**

```
# The statement has succesfully deleted c[0]
# >>> c
#[[3, 2], [3], [1]]

#The statement has succesfully cleared the list
# >>> r
#[]


# Basically, I want to delete each element to the left of the list until there is one element left. And then break. 

# (eg. 1234, 234, 34, and finally 5)
# There are 10 steps in this loop. because 1+2+3+4 == 10
```

While loop that is intended to do the statements above are now stuck in an infinite for loop.

```
c = [[1,3],[3,2],[3,4],[1]]
r=[];
while len(c) > 1:
    for j in range(1, len(c)):
        if str(any(elem in c[0] for elem in c[j])) == 'False':
            r.append(c[j])
            r.append(c[0])
            # we use print(r) to show bug
            print(r)
        if j == len(c) - 1:
            # This statement is intended to break an infinite loop but fails to do so.
            del c[0]
            r[:] = []
            if len(c) == 1:
                quit()



print(r)
```

output

```
[3,4],[1],[2,3],[1,3],[1,3]... infinite loop output
```

The output is not the problem. There is no need into getting into detail about the output. I just need to figure out how to loop through the list of elements as exemplified above.

### Question

*What are my mistakes in my while loop that make it an infinite loop?
Are there any solutions you can give me so that I can learn to not do the same mistake again?*

Comment: Note that converting a boolean to string to test it is very inefficient; `if str(any(elem in c[0] for elem in c[j])) == 'False':` should be written more simply `if not any(elem in c[0] for elem in c[j]):` or with sets intersection: `if not set(c[0]) & set(c[j]):`

Comment: You're switching between string, list, and nested list.  I, too, have trouble seeing why you are walking through this convoluted process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be it?

```
c = [[1,3], [3,2], [3,4], [1]]
r = []

while len(c) - 1:
    r.append(c.pop(0))

print("r", r, "\nc", c)

# results:
# r [[1, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4]] 
# c [[1]]
```

Comment: This should do. I will implement my other if statements to output my desired outputs.